# Referencing ViewGroup in android

Tags: android, viewgroup

I want to slide down a Relative layout in android withen an activity.
I have the following function that slides down a layout:

```
public void setLayoutAnim_slidedown(ViewGroup panel, Context ctx) {

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(800);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // MapContacts.this.mapviewgroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
            set, 0.25f);
    panel.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

}
```

as you see the parameter in the first line is of type ViewGroup ..My question is how can I reference the View group ...

Note I tried the following

```
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childView, null);
```

But this returns View not a groupView !

Comment: you can always typecast View to Viewgroup as ViewGroup is super class.

Comment: another question ... Do I have to do any thing extra than calling the function .. because the animation doesn't start by this way .. is there any thing missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just type cast the return result to `ViewGroup`, provided that your R.layout.childView starts with a ViewGroup, it would be fine:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup )inflater.inflate(R.layout.childView, null);
```

Comment: Yes. RelativeLayout is extended from ViewGroup

Comment: ok :) .. Why don't the animation starts after calling the following?

vg.startLayoutAnimation();

Comment: Not sure, from the code you have you just inflated the stuff, but no idea how you attach it to the window